# Flickering spinner caused by CSS clip?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

[Here's](http://codepen.io/omguhh/pen/bVyPBw?editors=110) how it looks

```
.spinner {
       position: absolute;
       top: 35%;
       left: 50%;
       height: 80px;
       width: 80px;
       margin: -40px 0 0 -40px;
       clip: rect(0, 80px, 80px, 40px);
       -webkit-animation: loading 1.5s linear infinite;
       animation: loading 1.5s linear infinite;
       transform-origin: center;

        &:after {
        content:'';
        position: absolute;
        height: 80px;
        width: 80px;
        clip: rect(0, 80px, 80px, 40px);
        border-radius: 50%;
        -webkit-animation: loading2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
       animation: loading2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
        }
     }

@-webkit-keyframes loading {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(220deg);
    transform: rotate(220deg);
  }
}
@keyframes loading {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(220deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes loading2 {
  0% {
    box-shadow: inset #5FA3F3 0 0 0 8px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-140deg);
    transform: rotate(-140deg);
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: inset #2771C9 0 0 0 2px;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset #5FA3F3 0 0 0 8px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(140deg);
    transform: rotate(140deg);
  }
}
@keyframes loading2 {
  0% {
    box-shadow: inset #5FA3F3 0 0 0 8px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-140deg);
    transform: rotate(-140deg);
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: inset #2771C9 0 0 0 2px;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset #5FA3F3 0 0 0 8px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(140deg);
    transform: rotate(140deg);
  }
}
```

On Firefox (version 42.0) the spinner stutters sometimes , and I believe it may be because of how the clipped rectangle is animating and rotating when its transition is over. I'm not sure how to fix this or if there's a better way to implement this spinner.

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't you use the vendor-prefix for mozilla too? e.g. `-moz-animation` , `-moz-transform`

Comment: For me, it stutters a in both, FF and Chrome. I guess this is related to the changing box-shadow size, which doesn't seem to be smoothened/anti-aliased.

Comment: @Chris You don't need to add vendor prefixes for mozilla. I've tried adding them for this but it made no difference.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach doesn't that apply just for fonts?

Comment: No; what I mean is that size seems to jump between whole numbers, i.e. *2px -> 3px -> 4px...*, rather than interpolating values inbetween, like *2.5px*. Maybe [this image](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/f0565e89933fbdcb9a84190e3b35acfce572eb93/68747470733a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f6f3838594f63352e706e67) (which is what it should do, but doesn't) helps you understand better.

Comment: Ah, now I see: The problem I'm describing isn't what's concerning you; it's the short flicker at the end of the animation. However, I didn't see this on Firefox while on Linux, just now on Windows, so it seems either FF-version or platform dependent...

Answer (score 0):

Try this! Apply it to the element you see the flicker on.

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

Little bit on what preserve-3d is about:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform-style/

**Update**

The example link you gave is `ease infinite`.
If you were to use `linear infinite` like the code you gave, I don't see any issue.

```
-webkit-animation: loading 1.5s linear infinite;
```

I tried to modify this from linear to ease, http://codepen.io/pksunkara/pen/gbejPv, it also resulted in the ending to flicker little. The best way to is to fix to single colour.

Comment: Tried this before, had no effect on it /:
I've also tried  
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: scale(1);

But it changed nothing. :(

Comment: Let me rewrite the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `z-index: 1` for the spinner. It worked for me when working with the bootstrap 4 spinner.